# Fixed item in the grid when using Isotope

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

**Case:**
I got a grid with images and two textboxes. I'm using [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html) to layout the grid and shuffle it.

**Problem:**
The textboxes should have a fixed position in the grid (no shuffle).
The images can shuffle.

**Question:**
How can I get elements in the grid to be fixed?
I found a site where it's been done, I just can't figure out how...
(http://www.facesofnyfw.com/)
Here, the first boxes (with the title and filter, ...) are fixed and do not move.

Thanks in advance,

Ibe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The previous answer is on the right path, but Isotope has released a new version that uses 'stamps' instead of 'corner-stamps'.  Check out the documentation [here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html#stamp).  It allows to you specify the position of certain elements on the page and then isotope will arrange all other items below/(around?) them.  I used it to fix an element in the top left corner of the container div, and it worked like a charm.  I imagine it might be more difficult to position things elsewhere, but I'm sure it possible!

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="stamp stamp1"></div>
  <div class="stamp stamp2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  ....
</div>
```

JS:

```
// specify itemSelector so stamps do get laid out
itemSelector: '.grid-item',
// stamp elements
stamp: '.stamp'
```

CSS:

```
/* position stamp elements with CSS */
.grid {
  position: relative;
}
.stamp {
  position: absolute;
  background: orange;
  border: 4px dotted black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the images to shuffle like water flows around stones in a lake? Don't think that's achievable unless you customise the plugin yourself. Shuffle randomises all element positions at once. [You can have a corner stamp though.](http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/xaE7F/) as shown by the pluging creator. Corner stamp - first item, not filtered out.